# Hibernate second level cache lazy collection size

Tags: hibernate, caching

We've enabled the second level cache on hibernate using the following properties:

```
hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class", "org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory");
hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache", Boolean.TRUE.toString());
hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", Boolean.TRUE.toString());
hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries", Boolean.TRUE.toString());     
hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.generate_statistics", Boolean.TRUE.toString());
```

And tagged our entities using the cache tag:

```
@Entity
@Indexed
@Table(name = "item")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.TRANSACTIONAL)
public class Item implements Serializable {
```

This entity has a lazy collection with the lazy collection option extra:

```
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.TRANSACTIONAL)
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = User.class, mappedBy = "likes")
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)
private List<User> users;
```

This seems to be working well and I don't see any database queries after the data has been cached, but what we do see are a log of calls to

```
select count(user_id) from user_items where item_id =?
```

Is there any way to get hibernate to cache the sizes of the lazy collection so it doesn't need to hit the database when we do users.size() ?

---

I have changed to CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE and see the same behaviour.

In the first request I see queries to select entities and the queries to find the size of the collections. I see log messages saying that the entities are being cached.

In subsequent requests there are no calls to load the entities, but there are still calls to find the sizes of the collections.

Answer (score -1):

You would never see a database query when data is cached. and you are saying that there are continuous logs of select queries.
Ehcache does not provide Transactional cache.
And you are saying that it is workin.
Brother it is not working you are just having database calls and logs of the same.
**Check Ehcache documentation as it does not support TRANSACTIONAL caching**

Comment: "Ehcache documentation as it does not support TRANSACTIONAL caching" - what does that mean, what do you think a transactional cache is  ?

Comment: I have changed to CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE and see the same behaviour. In the first request I see queries to select entities and the queries to find the size of the collections. I see log messages saying that the entities are being cached. In subsequent requests there are no calls to load the entities, but there are still calls to find the sizes of the collections.

Answer (score -1):

The list of users is a lazy loaded collection. 
In Lazy loaded collection you will not have any data.
Whenever you want to access the Lazy loaded collection or you want to determine the size of lazy loaded collection it must have information regarding data inside it, like how many elements are there.
For this it will get that data from database and will therefore generate database queries every time.
I checked the list on both as the uppermost level and inside some other objects.
Which shows that when List is not the top level object it will be lazily initialized.
Therefore whenever you would like to get information about the collection or from the collection it will generate database queries.